# What does <> mean in visual basic?

Tags: vb6, operators

I can't google it because google removes <> from the search even when surrounding it with quotes. So what does <> do in VB6?

Comment: If you are comparing numbers or strings it means "is different than". For instance, 1 <> 2, "Hello" <> "World".

Comment: @HanletEscaño: Actually, it means "not equal to", as in `1 is not equal to 2` (`1 <> 2`).

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, that's what I meant :D

Comment: Technically, it means 'less than' or 'greater than'. In this case it's the same thing as 'not equal to'. But to further explain things, you may also see <= (Less than or equal to) or >= (Greater than or equal to).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's the [inequality operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263418%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). Think of it as C-like languages version of a `!=`.

So `1 <> 2` evaluates to true, but `1 <> 1` does not.